# CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication fails to add authentication data to request

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, digest-authentication, cfnetwork

I'm trying to extend functionality of [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) library. I want to add authentication feature.

Since this library is using [`CFNetwork` `CFHTTPMessage*` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMessageRef/index.html) for HTTP functionality (needed to start web socket connection) I'm trying to utilize this API to provide authentication.
There is perfectly matching  function for that: `CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication`, but it doesn't work as I'm expecting (as I understand [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMessageRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication)).

Here is sample of code showing the problem:

```
- (CFHTTPMessageRef)createAuthenticationHandShakeRequest: (CFHTTPMessageRef)chalengeMessage {
    CFHTTPMessageRef request = [self createHandshakeRequest];
    BOOL result = CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication(request,
                                                 chalengeMessage,
                                                 (__bridge CFStringRef)self.credentials.user,
                                                 (__bridge CFStringRef)self.credentials.password,
                                                 kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeDigest, /* I've also tried NULL for use strongest supplied authentication */
                                                 NO);
    if (!result) {
        NSString *chalengeDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: CFBridgingRelease(CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(chalengeMessage))
                                                              encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString  *requestDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: CFBridgingRelease(CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(request))
                                                              encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        SRFastLog(@"Failed to add authentication data `%@` to a request:\n%@After a chalenge:\n%@",
                  self.credentials, requestDescription, chalengeDescription);
    }
    return request;
}
```

`requestDescription` content is:

```
GET /digest-auth/auth/user/passwd HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 3P5YiQDt+g/wgxHe71Af5Q==
Connection: Upgrade
Origin: http://httpbin.org/
```

`chalengeDescription` contains:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: fake=fake_value
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://httpbin.org/
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 12:21:33 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
Www-Authenticate: Digest nonce="0c7479b412e665b8685bea67580cf391", opaque="4ac236a2cec0fc3b07ef4d628a4aa679", realm="me@kennethreitz.com", qop=auth
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

`user` and `password` values are valid ("user" "passwd").

Why `CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication` returns `NO`? There is no clue what is the problem. I've also try updated with credentials an empty request but without luck.

I've used `http://httpbin.org/` just for testing (functionality of web socket is irrelevant at this step).

Please not that used code doesn't use (and never will) `NSURLRequst` or `NSURLSession` or `NSURLConnection`/

---

I've tried to use different functions: `CFHTTPAuthenticationCreateFromResponse` and `CFHTTPMessageApplyCredentials` with same result. 
At least `CFHTTPMessageApplyCredentials` returns some error information in form of `CFStreamError`. Problem is that this error information is useless: `error.domain = 4`, `error.error = -1000` where those values are not documented anywhere.
The only documented values looks like this:

```
typedef CF_ENUM(CFIndex, CFStreamErrorDomain) {
    kCFStreamErrorDomainCustom = -1L,      /* custom to the kind of stream in question */
    kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX = 1,        /* POSIX errno; interpret using <sys/errno.h> */
    kCFStreamErrorDomainMacOSStatus      /* OSStatus type from Carbon APIs; interpret using <MacTypes.h> */
};
```

`CFHTTPAuthenticationCreateFromResponse` returns invalid object, which description returns this:

```
<CFHTTPAuthentication 0x108810450>{state = Failed; scheme = <undecided>, forProxy = false}
```

I've found in documentation what those values means: `domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP`, `error=kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationTypeUnsupported` (thanks  @JensAlfke I've found it before your comment). Why it is unsupported? Documentation claims that digest is supported there is a constant `kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeDigest` which is accepted and expected by `CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication`!

---

I've dig up [source code of `CFNetwork` authentication](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-128/HTTP/CFHTTPAuthentication.c) and trying figure out what is the problem.

I have to do some mistake since this simple tast application also fails:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>

static NSString * const kHTTPAuthHeaderName = @"WWW-Authenticate";

static NSString * const kHTTPDigestChallengeExample1 = @"Digest realm=\"testrealm@host.com\", "
    "qop=\"auth,auth-int\", "
    "nonce=\"dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093\", "
    "opaque=\"5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41\"";

static NSString * const kHTTPDigestChallengeExample2 = @"Digest nonce=\"b6921981b6437a4f138ba7d631bcda37\", "
    "opaque=\"3de7d2bd5708ac88904acbacbbebc4a2\", "
    "realm=\"me@kennethreitz.com\", "
    "qop=auth";

static NSString * const kHTTPBasicChallengeExample1 = @"Basic realm=\"Fake Realm\"";

#define RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(a, x) if ((a) == (x)) return @ #x

NSString *NSStringFromCFErrorDomain(CFIndex domain) {
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainFTP);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainSystemConfiguration);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainSOCKS);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainMacOSStatus);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UnknownDomain=%ld", domain];
}

NSString *NSStringFromCFErrorError(SInt32 error) {
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(error, kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationTypeUnsupported);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(error, kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationBadUserName);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(error, kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationBadPassword);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UnknownError=%d", (int)error];
}

NSString *NSStringFromCFHTTPMessage(CFHTTPMessageRef message) {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData: CFBridgingRelease(CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(message))
                                 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

void testAuthenticationHeader(NSString *authenticatiohHeader) {
    CFHTTPMessageRef response = CFHTTPMessageCreateResponse(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                            401,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
    CFAutorelease(response);

    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(response,
                                     (__bridge CFStringRef)kHTTPAuthHeaderName,
                                     (__bridge CFStringRef)authenticatiohHeader);


    CFHTTPAuthenticationRef authData = CFHTTPAuthenticationCreateFromResponse(kCFAllocatorDefault, response);
    CFAutorelease(authData);

    CFStreamError error;
    BOOL validAuthData = CFHTTPAuthenticationIsValid(authData, &error);

    NSLog(@"testing header value: %@\n%@authData are %@   error.domain=%@  error.error=%@\n\n",
          authenticatiohHeader, NSStringFromCFHTTPMessage(response),
          validAuthData?@"Valid":@"INVALID",
          NSStringFromCFErrorDomain(error.domain), NSStringFromCFErrorError(error.error));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        testAuthenticationHeader(kHTTPDigestChallengeExample1);
        testAuthenticationHeader(kHTTPDigestChallengeExample2);
        testAuthenticationHeader(kHTTPBasicChallengeExample1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Logs show:

```
2015-07-01 16:33:57.659 cfauthtest[24742:600143] testing header value: Digest realm="testrealm@host.com", qop="auth,auth-int", nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093", opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Www-Authenticate: Digest realm="testrealm@host.com", qop="auth,auth-int", nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093", opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"

authData are INVALID   error.domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP  error.error=kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationTypeUnsupported

2015-07-01 16:33:57.660 cfauthtest[24742:600143] testing header value: Digest nonce="b6921981b6437a4f138ba7d631bcda37", opaque="3de7d2bd5708ac88904acbacbbebc4a2", realm="me@kennethreitz.com", qop=auth
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Www-Authenticate: Digest nonce="b6921981b6437a4f138ba7d631bcda37", opaque="3de7d2bd5708ac88904acbacbbebc4a2", realm="me@kennethreitz.com", qop=auth

authData are INVALID   error.domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP  error.error=kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationTypeUnsupported

2015-07-01 16:33:57.660 cfauthtest[24742:600143] testing header value: Basic realm="Fake Realm"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="Fake Realm"

authData are INVALID   error.domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP  error.error=kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationTypeUnsupported
```

---

edit after my own answer:

### Alternative solution

Other possible solution is to manually parse `WWW-Authenticate` response header and precess it and generate `Authorization` header for new request.

Is there some simple library or sample code I could use in commercial application which will do this (only this)? I could do this my self but this will take a precious time. Bounty is still available :).

Comment: Please note that this is low level API `CFHTTPMessage` which operates on `CFStream` and you are referring to higher level API `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`. For some strange reason `CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication` has refused to add authentication data to my request and there is no information why.

Comment: I see what you mean about the CFStream. Have you tried passing in the Auth object within the `NSURLRequest` (actually an `NSMutableURLRequest` object) with `- (id)initWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;`? Just not sure that when it runs through `_urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields` it will correctly add the Auth object using `CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(request, (__bridge CFStringRef)key, (__bridge CFStringRef)obj);`

Comment: @sbarow: aparently you don't understand the problem. `NSURLRequest` here is not available since HTTP is used only as a handshake to start web socket connection so lower level API is used for HTTP.

Comment: You're using Socket Rocket right? I don't know the in's and out's of your implementation but if you look in the header file (`SRWebSocket.h`) at line `64` you will see `- (id)initWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;` so `NSURLRequest` is in fact available. Like I say I don't know your implementation, so thats all the advise I can give. Good luck.

Comment: see [the source code of initWithURLRequest](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/blob/master/SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.m#L286). `NSURLRequest` is used only as temporary storage for headers and URL and nothing else. For HTTP protocol CFNetwork API is used only.

Comment: I looked up error -1000 on osstatus.com — it's kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationTypeUnsupported (as defined in CFHTTPAuthentication.h.) Which implies digest auth isn't supported; that's strange. Also, domain 4 is kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP.

Comment: Should the origin start as https to do the upgrade to wss?

Comment: @uchuugaka in this stage (HTTP handshake) web socket functionality is unimportant. It is digest authentication over HTTP.

Comment: @JensAlfke thanks! I've found this values in documentation yesterday. I agree that this is strange since documentation clearly states that digest is supported. I've also added a [link to source code of  `CFHTTPAuthentication.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-128/HTTP/CFHTTPAuthentication.c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering own question :(

### Apple `CFNetwork` API sucks

Problem is that response in `CFHTTPMessageRef` have hidden property `URL`.
You can read it: `CFHTTPMessageCopyRequestURL` not set it and it is needed to properly create authentication object from `CFHTTPMessageRef`. If `URL` property is empty authentication will fail.

So how come that is some cases response with authentication challenge contains `URL` in other cases not?
This working response comes from `CFReadStreamRef` created by `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest` as property of this stream. [Here is crappy example](http://jameswilliams.me/blog/distant_past/41). So since `SocketRocket` doesn't use `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest` this is a big problem which can't be simply overcome.

What is sad that `CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication` could fetch this `URL` from request it modifies if it can't be found in response.

### Workaround

There is perfectly working workaround on this issue! But it involves use of private API (so most probably it will not pass Apple review). Here is full sample code with workaround (same as in question but applying this workaround), the workaround it self it just two lines: exposing private API and using it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>

static NSString * const kHTTPAuthHeaderName = @"WWW-Authenticate";

static NSString * const kHTTPDigestChallengeExample1 = @"Digest realm=\"testrealm@host.com\", "
    "qop=\"auth,auth-int\", "
    "nonce=\"dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093\", "
    "opaque=\"5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41\"";

static NSString * const kHTTPDigestChallengeExample2 = @"Digest nonce=\"b6921981b6437a4f138ba7d631bcda37\", "
    "opaque=\"3de7d2bd5708ac88904acbacbbebc4a2\", "
    "realm=\"me@kennethreitz.com\", "
    "qop=auth";

static NSString * const kHTTPBasicChallengeExample1 = @"Basic realm=\"Fake Realm\"";

#define RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(a, x) if ((a) == (x)) return @ #x

NSString *NSStringFromCFErrorDomain(CFIndex domain) {
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainHTTP);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainFTP);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainSystemConfiguration);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainSOCKS);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(domain, kCFStreamErrorDomainMacOSStatus);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UnknownDomain=%ld", domain];
}

NSString *NSStringFromCFErrorError(SInt32 error) {
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(error, kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationTypeUnsupported);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(error, kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationBadUserName);
    RETURN_STRING_IF_CONSTANT(error, kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationBadPassword);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UnknownError=%d", (int)error];
}

NSString *NSStringFromCFHTTPMessage(CFHTTPMessageRef message) {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData: CFBridgingRelease(CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(message))
                                 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

// exposing private API for workaround
extern void _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseURL(CFHTTPMessageRef, CFURLRef);

void testAuthenticationHeader(NSString *authenticatiohHeader) {
    CFHTTPMessageRef response = CFHTTPMessageCreateResponse(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                            401,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
    CFAutorelease(response);

    // workaround: use of private API
    _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseURL(response, (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://some.test.url.com/"]);

    CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(response,
                                     (__bridge CFStringRef)kHTTPAuthHeaderName,
                                     (__bridge CFStringRef)authenticatiohHeader);


    CFHTTPAuthenticationRef authData = CFHTTPAuthenticationCreateFromResponse(kCFAllocatorDefault, response);
    CFAutorelease(authData);

    CFStreamError error;
    BOOL validAuthData = CFHTTPAuthenticationIsValid(authData, &error);

    NSLog(@"testing header value: %@\n%@authData are %@   error.domain=%@  error.error=%@\n\n",
          authenticatiohHeader, NSStringFromCFHTTPMessage(response),
          validAuthData?@"Valid":@"INVALID",
          NSStringFromCFErrorDomain(error.domain), NSStringFromCFErrorError(error.error));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        testAuthenticationHeader(kHTTPDigestChallengeExample1);
        testAuthenticationHeader(kHTTPDigestChallengeExample2);
        testAuthenticationHeader(kHTTPBasicChallengeExample1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And result in logs looks like that:

```
2015-07-03 11:47:02.849 cfauthtest[42766:934054] testing header value: Digest realm="testrealm@host.com", qop="auth,auth-int", nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093", opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Www-Authenticate: Digest realm="testrealm@host.com", qop="auth,auth-int", nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093", opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"

authData are Valid   error.domain=UnknownDomain=0  error.error=UnknownError=0

2015-07-03 11:47:02.852 cfauthtest[42766:934054] testing header value: Digest nonce="b6921981b6437a4f138ba7d631bcda37", opaque="3de7d2bd5708ac88904acbacbbebc4a2", realm="me@kennethreitz.com", qop=auth
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Www-Authenticate: Digest nonce="b6921981b6437a4f138ba7d631bcda37", opaque="3de7d2bd5708ac88904acbacbbebc4a2", realm="me@kennethreitz.com", qop=auth

authData are Valid   error.domain=UnknownDomain=0  error.error=UnknownError=0

2015-07-03 11:47:02.852 cfauthtest[42766:934054] testing header value: Basic realm="Fake Realm"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="Fake Realm"

authData are Valid   error.domain=UnknownDomain=0  error.error=UnknownError=0
```

So workaround works.

I will keep looking for other workaround which will use public API only. At least now I know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `kCFStreamErrorHTTPAuthenticationTypeUnsupported`

Does `kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic` work?

Just a thought?

*edit* another thought, I've seen this when using the wrong protocol & port i.e.

`http://myauth.com/auth/.../foobar (on port 443 despite being http)`

and

`https://myauth.com/auth/.../foobar (on port 80 despite being https)`

Comment: I've tested this also for Basic authentication with same result. I've to do something wrong and error reporting doesn't show what exactly is a problem. Checkout last update of question, there is full code of sample application showing that something is wrong.

Comment: This is not port problem for sure. I used this URL in other test (where `NSURLSession`, `POCO library` and other libraries on other platforms) and it was working. Also proble is not network communication but parsing the authentication data (my code proves that if you read logs).

Comment: Have you confirmed that with tcpdump or another packet analyser like packetpeeper form packetpeeper.org ? Knowing if its on the net side or on the auth data side would cut down a lot of places to look :)

Comment: This is not a network problem. I'm receiving proper authentication challenge and by debugging I've narrow down problem to issue with adding credentials when building new request. Please read question more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some `CFHTTPAuthentication` code several months ago, and vaguely recall similar weirdness. I think the calls only worked correctly in combination with `CFStream`.

Meaning, `kCFStreamPropertyHTTPResponseHeader` was somehow different from a `CFHTTPMessage` created via `CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty` or `CFHTTPMessageCreateResponse`.

I'm not 100% on that though & don't have time to test right now.

Comment: socket rocket uses `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` and `CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty` so this might be a some clue. I will investigate this.

Comment: Form other source (tech lead from company I cooperate with) I have explanation why it doesn't work. He claims that there is not strait workaround, but your clue give me idea how I could do a workaround without implementing digest authentication my self. This might  solve this problem but it could break other stuff. I will post an answer when I will have clear view of problem and solution.